# Get the Value from another PHP page

Tags: php, html, get

Hello I have the below form in my page `viewsensordata.php`

```
...

$refresh = ($_POST['refresh']);

$link_address="viewsensordata.php?view=".$view;
?>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $link_address;?>">
<select id="refresh" name="refresh">
    <option value="-">Select Seconds</option>
    <option value="1">1 Second</option>
    <option value="2">2 Seconds</option>
    <option value="3">3 Seconds</option>
    <option value="4">4 Seconds</option>
    <option value="5">5 Seconds</option>
    <option value="10">10 Seconds</option>
    <option value="15">15 Seconds</option>
    <option value="30">30 Seconds</option>
    <option value="60">60 Seconds</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Refresh" name="refresh_rate"/>
</form>
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="<?php echo $refresh;?>;URL=refreshsensorData.php">
<br />
```

And I want to get the value of the `$refresh` to another page named `viewsensordata2.php`

In my `viewsensordata2.php` i have `$refresh = ($_GET['refresh']);` in order to GET it from the other page but it doesnt work. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$link_address="viewsensordata.php?view=".$view;
?>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $link_address;?>">
<select id="refresh" name="refresh">
    <option value="-">Select Seconds</option>
    <option value="1">1 Second</option>
    <option value="2">2 Seconds</option>
    <option value="3">3 Seconds</option>
    <option value="4">4 Seconds</option>
    <option value="5">5 Seconds</option>
    <option value="10">10 Seconds</option>
    <option value="15">15 Seconds</option>
    <option value="30">30 Seconds</option>
    <option value="60">60 Seconds</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Refresh" name="refresh_rate"/>
</form>
```

Then in your second page, you can refresh it like this:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST) && isset($_POST['refresh'])){
   $sec = $_POST['refresh'];
}
elseif(isset($_GET) && isset($_GET['seconds'])){
   $sec = $_GET['seconds'];
}
else{
   $sec = 10; // your defualt seconds, if it is not set from form or URL
}
?>

<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="<?php echo $sec ;?> URL=<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>?seconds=$sec">
```

Comment: So in the second page i will add the code that you wrote and how i will alter this part `<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0;URL=refreshsensorData.php?refresh=<?php echo $refresh;?>">`

Comment: @DogFace Depends on what you want, if you don't submit the form on first page, it will refresh do `refreshsensorData.php` after x seconds, there you can still access session. If you do submit the form before refresh, you will still be able to get session value in `viewsensordata.php` page.

Comment: What I want to do is to select from the form in the first page the seconds for the refresh rate and then in the second page to refresh my page with the selected refresh rate.

Comment: @DogFace Check the updated answer, then you simply access value of `$_POST['refresh']` in your second page and set a refresh meta header

Comment: Ok I did what you write but it will refresh the page only once , I want to refresh the page for example every 3 seconds if i selected 3 from the form

Comment: And also why you delete this code from the first page `<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="<?php echo $refresh;?>;URL=refreshsensorData.php">`

Comment: @DogFaceBecause it will refresh the page that has the form, you don't want that, do you ?

Comment: If i delete it then the form does not do anything

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81648/discussion-between-dogface-and-muhammet).